# Black screen in windows xp after full malware scan

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

Is this unavoidable? I make full malware and virus scans twice a month and I notice that after scanning, removing malware and rebooting windows only a black screen appears. Do you know of some ways on how to prevent this? Or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could really be anything, but not that likely to be malware - most (but obviously not all) modern malware is not always so much about doing damage per se, but instead they are designed to go unnoticed them selves and then do damage to remote targets and/or extract information.

If it is every time, your Anti Virus may have some sort of bug or be targeting a critical Windows file as a false positive.

To try and prevent this, I really need more information - how do you fix the problem? What is the file that gets removed? And, what anti virus do you use?

Apart from that, if you are still having problems, I would recommend switching to a good Anti Virus such as [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) which works very well.

Comment: I use avast free antivirus, mse sucks at detecting flash drive virus. I fixed the problem by booting to last known good configuration. So I also asked here how to prevent it

Comment: Well, check the Avast log and see what it deleted and try adding that to an exclusion list. I have not had any problems with MSE and flash drives - Go to advanced and enable scan USB drives, it isn't set by default.

Comment: Definitely check the logs to see what is being changed. No, it's not normal for a black screen after a virus scan, but it *is* possible that malware has replaced a system file, and the process of cleaning it has damaged Windows. Check what file(s) are being replaced, then scan that file with another AV or upload a copy of that file (boot to a safe mode or command line or a liveCD of Linux to get a copy of the file in question) to a website that does mass-scanning of files using a variety of tools and reports the results.